In Pads layout VX.2.13 is there any setting that can be checked so that it will not automatically delete my vias that are not connected to a trace?
I often put in grids of filled vias under the pads of SMD power transistors, under power supply modules, or in copper shapes for the purpose of conducting heat away from these parts to some other piece of copper.
I am using pads layout VX.2.13 and the tool has a habit of randomly deleting all the vias in my design that are not connected to a trace.
In Siemens (formerly Mentor Graphics) Pads layout VX.2.13 is there any setting that can be checked so that the tool will not automatically delete my vias that are not connected to a trace?

Can you define them as stitching vias?

@Andyaka I can, but I don't know if that will protect them from deletion or not.


I am using pads layout VX.2.13 and the tool has a habit of randomly
deleting all the vias in my design that are not connected to a trace.

I'm fairly sure that if you define the via as a stitching via then it won't automatically get deleted like a regular via. Easy enough to try out.
